# Use List<T> in Virtual Memory or Memory Map File

Tags: c#, virtual-memory, memory-mapped-files

i have 46 GB TXT File

i need to remove duplicate and other method

i think need to load into memory and haven't enough space available...

anyone have a method to load 46 GB TXT File as `List<T>` or `object` on 4GB RAM as Virtual Memory or Memory Map File?

**No need speed or performance!**

Comment: What's the structure of the text file? What do you mean by "and other method"? Are you removing duplicate *lines*, or something else? How many duplicates do you expect there to be? We need a lot more context before we can really help you...

Comment: If speed is not a concern but RAM very limited, then why not do everything with regular file IO?

Comment: i want to remove duplicate lines and other function of `List<T>`

Comment: i just need use a object in disk not memory This is the purpose of my question

Comment: Insert all the data into a SQLite table with a single column, then do `SELECT DISTINCT` from that table and column. Uses almost no memory if you read the file line-by-line using something like `File.ReadLines()` and insert the line into SQLite immediately after.

Comment: good but after him i need export him as txt file... but what can do for Randomize Text Lines?

Comment: Another idea: read the file line by line; for each line `string` use `GetHashCode()`; check if the hash already exists in a `HashSet`; if yes, then skip to the next line; if no, then store that hash and append that line to an output file. `GetHashCode()` _might_ create the same hash for different lines. To fix that you could also store the first found line number for each hash. Then, if a hash is matched, read the line at that file postion again to double check that both lines are identical.

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride - and if they're *not* identical? You now know of at least two lines that hash the same but under your scheme you're only remembering a maximum of one of those, so when you next encounter that same hash...

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, yep you're right. Stupid me 

Comment: "And other function of `List<T>`" is just as vague as "and other method". If you can't be specific about your requirements, we're not going to be able to help you.

Comment: @JonSkeet its "and other method" for example:
`
private static Random rng = new Random();

        public static void Shuffle<T>(this IList<T> list)
        {
            int n = list.Count;
            while (n > 1)
            {
                n--;
                int k = rng.Next(n + 1);
                T value = list[k];
                list[k] = list[n];
                list[n] = value;
            }
        }`
OR
`list.Distinct()`

Comment: But do you *actually* need to do either of those things? Surely you must know what you need to do with the file. You're simply *not* going to be able to access it like a normal `List<T>` - but you may be able to implement your *real* requirements. Without knowing those requirements though, we're not going to be able to help you.

Comment: (The closest I'd suggest you could come would be to just create a database with one record per line. That will let you do *some* of what you want. Not all though, potentially. Hard to say without concrete requirements...

Answer (score 2):

Open the file with random access, but read it sequentially. Whenever you read a whole line calculate a hash code of this line, and check if you already calculated this hash code. Store the hash code, together with file offset of the line in a [MultiValueDictionary](https://github.com/dotnet/corefxlab/blob/archive/src/Microsoft.Experimental.Collections/Microsoft/Collections/Extensions/MultiValueDictionary.cs) (hash code as key, file offset as value). So whenever you read a new line and calculate its hash code you check if you already have the hash code. If you have it then you also must verify that lines match byte for byte (and you have one or more file offsets of previous lines, so if one of those lines match the current line byte for byte, then you have a duplicate).

If you have a duplicate line, then just continue reading. If you have a new line then write the line in a new file. This new file will contain only unique lines in the end.

You will have to remember your progress with the original file, because you will go back and forth. Back to compare old lines, forth to read new lines.

Comment: Had the same idea at the same time ^^ But there is no need for a `MultiValueDictionary`. Just use a regular dictionary and store the file position of the line found first. Saves some memory.

Comment: @good suppose we have three different lines with the same hash code. When the third line is encountered you have to compare it with both previous lines. So you have to know the offsets of both of them.

Comment: Of course! Stupid me 

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride thanks for you replay and its good idea i will test him but i say "other method" duplicate remover is a part of question i need Randomize lines and add other `List<T>` to him and merge him and other work... for this work of project i 100% need Virtual Memory or Memory Map File object to use better fast....

Comment: @MGToken you do not need memory mapped files for this, and it would not help you since you cannot treat a memory mapped file as a list. Whatever operation you need to do, you can do it by processing a list of offsets for the file. Randomization is done by simply shuffling the list. If you have multiple files the offset should also include some way to identify the source file.

Comment: @MGToken you have to tell us everything you want to do with the file. And also how do you want the result to appear. Is a new file a good output, or do you want the changes to be applied to the original file? So, I gave you `Distinct` method. It seems you want indexed read/write access to every line (`line[n]`), and also `Count` property. Or maybe just some kind of `Shuffle` method. Which is it, just a shuffle or you actually need indexed access. Also, what else do you want?

Comment: @Dialecticus Shuffle Distinct  Count  Add Remove Add range find etc... from a list<t> after process on source file we will have a output of txt file

Comment: if need we will merge another 26GB txt to 46GB txt line by line its can't use on RAM

Comment: @MGToken I think you should work with a database.